# Cardview with child view's inside OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-cardview, android-viewgroup

```
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="170dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/home_toolbar_open_kin_marketplace_card_view"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/kinecosystem_bluePrimaryDark">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1.8"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:focusable="false"
                                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                                    android:padding="3dp"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:src="@drawable/kinecosystem_kin_logo"/>
                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:focusable="false"
                                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                                    android:id="@+id/home_toolbar_current_kin_balance_text_view"
                                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                                    android:layout_weight="1"
                                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                    android:layout_gravity="start"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/serifgothicstdbold"/>

                            </LinearLayout>
                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:orientation="horizontal">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:focusable="false"
                                    android:duplicateParentState="true"
                                    android:id="@+id/home_toolbar_kin_balance_status_text_view"
                                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                    android:textSize="12sp"
                                    android:textIsSelectable="true"
                                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                                    android:fontFamily="@font/serifgothicstdbold"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>


                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

JAVA CODE:-

```
public class HomeActivityClass extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeActivityView, View.OnClickListener, BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener{

private Cardview openKinMarketPlaceButton;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        setViews();
        openKinMarketPlaceButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
    public void setViews() {
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        homeBottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.home_bottom_navigation_view);
        homeToolbarLayout = findViewById(R.id.home_activity_home_toolbar);
        userAvatarImageView = homeToolbarLayout.findViewById(R.id.home_activity_user_profile_image_view);
        openKinMarketPlaceButton = homeToolbarLayout.findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar_open_kin_marketplace_card_view);
        currentKinBalanceTextView = homeToolbarLayout.findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar_current_kin_balance_text_view);
        kinBalanceStatusTextView = homeToolbarLayout.findViewById(R.id.home_toolbar_kin_balance_status_text_view);
        deviceScreenSizeValidation();
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == openKinMarketPlaceButton){
            homeActivityPresenter.onKinButtonClicked();
        }
    }
}
```

openKinMarketplaceButton is a card view.
The OnClickListener for it isn't working.
How to add OnClickListener to a viewgroup with child views inside.
OnClick works on image view click, which is inside card view.
I want to use card view as a button in all over the app, as the buttons have images in a complex position and text also.

Comment: Put breakpoint in `if` statement and check is `homeActivityPresenter.onKinButtonClicked()` reached by compiler when is clicked?

Comment: the onClick is working only for image view and not for other view's (text view and card view)
added a log in if statement, which log's only on image view click

Comment: it doesn't satisfy's the if statement for view's excpet imageview

Comment: Your code is little bi confusing you are extending `AppCompatActivity` but there is no `setContentView`. Second one is using `homeToolbarLayout` to get id of `CardView` and third one is comparison in `onClick` where probably should go like: 
`v.getId() == R.id.home_toolbar_open_kin_marketplace_card_view`

Comment: SetContentView is there. I haven't added it in question

Comment: Trying your method with id

Comment: HomeToolbar is a custom toolbar layout which is included in main layout

Comment: Still not working, same problem

Comment: Is it due to match_parent attribute of child views